# How to set the defaultvalue as a parameter taking function in django where the parameter is the value of one of the fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to set the default value of image field as the getimg function. But when I run this code I get an error saying missing one required positional argument in getimg() 'self'. How do I approach this?

```
class Products(models.Model):

Code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Product_description = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key = True)
Val_tech = models.CharField(max_length=5)
Quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
UOM = models.CharField(max_length=5)
Rate = models.FloatField(default=0)
Value = models.FloatField(default=0)


def __str__(self):
    return self.Product_description


class Forimg(models.Model):

products = models.OneToOneField(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)

def getimg(self):
    item = self.products.Product_description
    page = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q={item}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    item_head = soup.find('img',class_='t0fcAb')
    return item_head['src']

image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'img/', width_field= 30, height_field = 40,default=getimg)


def __str__(self):
    return self.products.Product_description
```

Comment: `default=getimg()` instead of `default=getimg`?

Comment: I'd say rather `getimg` should be a static method without any arguments.

Comment: you can call getimg() with an object of the class , getimg should be a class method inside the class .

Comment: @Charnel How do I access the field value through a static method?

Comment: @Stevy I get this error when I do that:   getimg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: @MohitHarshan i get this error when I do that :   'classmethod' object is not callable

Comment: @MoonC you can't access fields value using static method. Answer offered by kaajavi should work unless your method retrieve not a full path to image.

Answer (score 0):

You can override save method.

```
class Forimg(models.Model):

    products = models.OneToOneField(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)

    def getimg(self):
        item = self.products.Product_description
        page = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q={item}')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
        item_head = soup.find('img',class_='t0fcAb')
        return item_head['src']

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'img/', width_field= 30, height_field = 40,default=None)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.products.Product_description
    
    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        if not self.image and self.products:
            self.image = self.getimg()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I made a new entry in my Products table. I did this but I don't see a new image object being created .